# jQuery not calculating total height div's dynamically added children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height, children

Could you please help understand why it is not working and help make it work?

I am trying to calculate the total height of all the children elements that are dynamically added/placed to DIV element, the code is not working [i.e. the number of children elements will vary every time]. The code is returning the initial defined value of zero when i checked the returned value on the console.log().

Here is the code and print scrreen:

```
 //This is the code that dynamically extracts data every second from the server and populates it into to DIV element.
            setInterval(function() {
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
                    var temp3 = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        temp3 += '<p>' + data[i].join() + '</p>';
                    }
                    document.getElementById("item1").innerHTML = temp3;
                }).getReadyLine();
            }, 1000);

//This is the code that should calculate the total height of all the children elements of DIV element. But it is not working, not calculating, it displays 0 on the console.log().
            var outerHeight1 = 0;
            $("#item1").children().each(function() {
                outerHeight1 += $(this).outerHeight();
            });
        </script>
//This is the code for DIV.
        <div class="item1" id="item1">
```

[image: Print Screen]

**PS**

```
Update: included the code inside setInerval like this:
<script>

    $( document ).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
                var temp3 = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    temp3 += '<p>' + data[i] + '</p>';
                }
                document.getElementById("item1").innerHTML = temp3;
            }).getReadyLine();
            var outerHeight1 = 0;
                $("#item1").children().each(function() {
                  outerHeight1 += $(this).outerHeight(true);
                  return outerHeight1;
                });
                console.log(outerHeight1);
        }, 1000);

        /*
        var outerHeight1 = 0;
        $("#item1").children().each(function() {
            outerHeight1 += $(this).outerHeight();
        }); */

        var outerHeight2 = 0;
        $("#item2").children().each(function() {
            outerHeight2 += $(this).outerHeight(true);
        })

        $("#item1").animate({
            scrollTop: outerHeight1
        }, 10000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#item1").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 10000);
        }, 3000);
        setInterval(function() {
            // 4000 - it will take 4 secound in total from the top of the page to the bottom
            $("#item1").animate({
                scrollTop: outerHeight1
            }, 10000);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#item1").animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 10000);
            }, 4000);

        }, 4000);

        $("#item2").animate({
            scrollTop: outerHeight2
        }, 8000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#item2").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 8000);
        }, 8000);
        setInterval(function() {
            // 4000 - it will take 4 secound in total from the top of the page to the bottom
            $("#item2").animate({
                scrollTop: outerHeight2
            }, 8000);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#item2").animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 8000);
            }, 8000);

        }, 8000);

        console.log($("#item1").outerHeight());
        console.log(outerHeight1);
        });




    </script>
```

Comment: If you can post a fiddle or the code snippet here, it would be helpful.

Comment: The problem is that you're calculating the hight only once and that is done before any elements are added to `#item1`

Comment: Exactly... you are doing it outside of `setInterval`

Comment: What `console.log()` ? You've probably calling `console.log(outerHeight1)` outside of the `setInterval` callback which means that that statement is executed before `outerHeight1` is set. Just take a moment to thing about the order of execution of each function and the context of each variable.

Comment: I just included the code inside setInterval, it works but there is another setInterval outside that animates(scrolls up and down) repeatedly that does not see the outerHeight and it displays error: outerHeight1 is not defined: Please see the updated code in the message above in the PS section at the very end. Thank you.

Comment: Titus, yes correct. I have included console.log() in order to see what error it would give. Please see the above code, I have added the full code in <script></script>.

Comment: I don't know how to pass the value of variable outerHeight1 from the first setInterval (that extracts data from the server and populates the div children) to the second setInterval (that animates the div by scrolling down and up repeatedly). The variable outerHeight1 is not visible outside the first setInterval where it is calculating the total height of the dynamic children elements of DIV.

Comment: It works now :-) Thank you guys for the hints. I will post the updated code, it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the hints on one time calculation and embedding code inside the setInterval part.

Here is the code that works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#item1").animate({
                scrollTop: $("#item1").height()
            }, 4000);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#item1").animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 4000);
            }, 4000);

            setInterval(function() {
                // 4000 - it will take 4 secound in total from the top of the page to the bottom
                $("#item1").animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#item1").height()
                }, 4000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#item1").animate({
                        scrollTop: 0
                    }, 4000);
                }, 4000);

            }, 8000);
        });

        var totalHeight = 0;

        $("#leftcolumn").children().each(function() {
            totalHeight = totalHeight + $(this).outerHeight(true);
        });

        var outerHeight = 0;
        $('.profile').each(function() {
            outerHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
        });
        $("#total-height").text(outerHeight + 'px');

        setInterval(function() {
            google.script.run.withSuccesshandler(function(data) {
                $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
                    out += "<li>" + $(this).val() + "</li>";
                });
                out += "</ul>";

                $('#listView').html(out);
            }).getReadyLine();
        }, 50000);

        $('#mybutt').click(function() {
            var out = '<ul>';
            $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
                out += "<li>" + $(this).val() + "</li>";
            });
            out += "</ul>";

            $('#listView').html(out);
        });
        setInterval(function() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = whatToWrite;
            }).getReadyLine();
        }, 1000);

        setInterval(function() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var temp3 = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    temp3 = 'p' + i + '/p';
                    document.getElementById("#item1").innerHTML = temp3;
                }
            }).getReadyLine();
        }, 1000);


        setInterval(function() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
                var temp3 = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    temp3 = 'p' + data[i] + '/p';
                    document.getElementById("#item1").innerHTML = temp3;
                    temp3 = '';
                }
            }).getReadyLine();
        }, 1000);

        //This is the server side code that returns the data, it works fine, have checked it;
        function getReadyLine() {
            var rawData = sheetMAT.getRange(3, 2, sheetMAT.getLastRow() - 2, 5).getValues();
            for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
                if (rawData[i][3] === "A Ready Line" && rawData[i][4] === "ATY") {
                    temp1 = ' ' + data[i][0];
                    temp2.push(data[i][1], temp1);
                    dataReadyLine.push(temp2);
                    temp1 = '';
                    temp2 = [];
                }
            }
            return dataReadyLine;
        }

        //This is the client side code that should populate the innerHTML of the DIV template that is shown below;
        setInterval(function() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
                var temp3 = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    temp3 = 'p' + data[i] + '/p';
                    document.getElementById("#item1").innerHTML = temp3;
                    temp3 = '';
                }
            }).getReadyLine();
        }, 10000);

        setInterval(function() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
                var temp3 = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    temp3 += '<p>' + data[i].join() + '</p>';
                }
                document.getElementById("item1").innerHTML = temp3;
            }).getReadyLine();
        }, 1000);

        //This is the code that dynamically extracts data every second from the server and populates it into to DIV element.
        setInterval(function() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
                var temp3 = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    temp3 += '<p>' + data[i].join() + '</p>';
                }
                document.getElementById("item1").innerHTML = temp3;
            }).getReadyLine();
        }, 1000);

        //This is the code that should calculate the total height of all the children elements of DIV element. But it is not working, not calculating.
        var outerHeight1 = 0;
        $("#item1").children().each(function() {
            outerHeight1 += $(this).outerHeight();
        });


        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
                    var temp3 = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        temp3 += '<p>' + data[i] + '</p>';
                    }
                    document.getElementById("item1").innerHTML = temp3;
                }).getReadyLine();
                var outerHeight1 = 0;
                $("#item1").children().each(function() {
                    outerHeight1 += $(this).outerHeight(true);
                });
                console.log(outerHeight1);
                $("#item1").animate({
                    scrollTop: outerHeight1
                }, 8000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#item1").animate({
                        scrollTop: 0
                    }, 8000);
                }, 1000);
                setInterval(function() {
                    // 4000 - it will take 4 secound in total from the top of the page to the bottom
                    $("#item1").animate({
                        scrollTop: outerHeight1
                    }, 8000);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#item1").animate({
                            scrollTop: 0
                        }, 8000);
                    }, 8000);

                }, 1000);
            }, 1000);

            var outerHeight2 = 0;
            $("#item2").children().each(function() {
                outerHeight2 += $(this).outerHeight(true);
            })

            $("#item2").animate({
                scrollTop: outerHeight2
            }, 8000);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#item2").animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 8000);
            }, 8000);
            setInterval(function() {
                // 4000 - it will take 4 secound in total from the top of the page to the bottom
                $("#item2").animate({
                    scrollTop: outerHeight2
                }, 8000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#item2").animate({
                        scrollTop: 0
                    }, 8000);
                }, 8000);

            }, 8000);

        });
```

Comment: You made this way more complicated then it has to be. The jQuery `animate` function has a lot of callback function for different stages of the animation (when the animation gets started, when it completes, etc.) you can find more details about that [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). For example, instead of using `setTimeout` you can do this: `$("#item1").amimate({scrollTop: $("#item1").height()}, 4000, function(){$(this).animate({scrollTop: 0}, 4000)}))`

Comment: I have the "#item1" with fixed height, as there is boxes next to it and below it. And also i could not make it repeatedly scroll down and up without **setTimeout**.